# CSS / jQuery improved page flow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make my web page flow better but I don't know what it's called that I am searching for!

Lets say I have the following HTML:

```
<section>
  <article>
    <h1>Article Header</h1>
    <p>Article content</p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h1>Article Header</h1>
    <p>Article content</p>
    <p>More content</p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h1>Article Header</h1>
    <p>Article content</p>
    <p>More content</p>
    <p>More content</p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h1>Article Header</h1>
    <p>Article content</p>
    <p>More content</p>
    <p>More content</p>
    <p>More content</p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h1>Article Header</h1>
    <p>Article content</p>
    <p>More content</p>
    <p>More content</p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h1>Article Header</h1>
    <p>Article content</p>
    <p>More content</p>
  </article>
```

and the following CSS

```
section article {
  width: 49%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

That makes the articles appear side by side in the section, but there are gaps where the articles different sizes.

How would I make it flow so there were no gaps (ie fill the available space) ?

I am open to a solution using jQuery / JavaScript if needs be.

fiddle added:

http://jsfiddle.net/Yn4et/

Comment: Linking to a jsfiddle.net would have made me want to look at this.

Comment: i guess you want something in which if the article size increases then  the overflow that comes in that particular  article should be removed.? how about overflow scroll / hidden

Comment: no, I want the content to be shifted up to make better use of the space without forcing the boxes to be smaller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand correctly what you want, but I think this is a duplicate of the following question:

[How to Create Grid/Tile View with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470070/how-to-create-grid-tile-view-with-css)

Answer (score 0):

```
section {
   width: 100%;
}

article {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}
```