# CSS have img on the same column but different line

Tags: html, css

I'm in a situation since 3 day and I don't have found any answer to my question : how have div  on the same width (containing images with a width of 320px) on the column (that's done) but not organize in line ?

Let me join a little sketch to explain that : at the left, it's what I've. At the right, it's what I want. (the second line is for the "media screen" when reducing the width of the screen/navigator : so have 4 to 3 to 2 to 1 (and vice versa). take care of the number of boxes) :

[image: croquis of what I have and what I want]

To explain how I've obtain this right part, here are the code :

html:

```
<div class="box">
<a href="#"><img src="#" alt=""/></a>
</div>
```

Simply a succession of this class, it can be directly on the body.
The box is important because maybe I'll have to had tittles or others things.

css:

```
.box {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    min-width: 340px;
    max-width: 24.80%;
    width: 24.79%;
    margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1800px) {
    .box {
        min-width: 360px;
        max-width: 33%;
        width: 33%;
    }   
}
```

To complete this question, here are a restriction : it had to be dynamic and generic (so like that, I just have to make a copy of a div and replace the link of the image (that's before adding php and js), or add anything I want).

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470070/how-to-create-grid-tile-view-with-css

Comment: As @ArionaRian suggests, Masonry in my experience is the only portable and out of the box solution to this problem.

Comment: http://masonry.desandro.com

Comment: There are other libraries that do the same thing, but a JavaScript option is the only valid one you have at the moment

Comment: thank you guys, I'll check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out jQuery Masonry (http://masonry.desandro.com), which does exactly what you need.

If you cant use Masonry for some reason, you should first split your page in columns. Then stack div boxes in each column.

Comment: columns doesn't like a good idea : if you apply columns, the third one of the top right part of my sketch will not transform at the bottom right part of my sketch.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. For responsive realignment, you should probably use jQuery Masonry.

Comment: for CSS3 solution, you can use column property. but as we now, it's still not supported in all browser. The best choice for now is using Masonry :)

Answer (score 0):

I had just tried to make like that right picture & I made that with seven div and all are in same width plus all picture in it are 320px same on size.I haven't tried with width.No media work I have to learn them too :)

```
  <body>
    <div id='box1'>1</div>
    <div id='box2'>2</div>
    <div id='box3'>3</div>
    <div id='box4'>4</div>
    <div id='box5'>5</div>
    <div id='box6'>6</div>
    <div id='box7'>7</div>
  </body>


    /* css code!*/

     body
        {   
          margin: 0px;
        }

     #box1
        {
          width:450px;
          height:300px;
          background-image: url('sheep.jpg');
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-color: #da1;
          background-size:320px; 
          position:absolute;
          left:1px; 
        }

     #box2
        {
          width:450px;
          height:380px;
          background-image: url('sheep.jpg');
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: 320px;
          position: absolute;
          left:451px;
          background-color:#df4;  
        }   

     #box3
        {
          width:450px;
          height:195px;
          background-image: url('sheep.jpg');
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: 320px;
          position: absolute;
          top:0px;
          left:901px;
          background-color:#dd6; 
        }   

     #box4
        {
          width:450px;
          height:658px;
          background-image: url('sheep.jpg');
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: 320px;
          position: absolute;
          left:1px;
          top:300px;
          background-color:#ced; 
        }           

     #box5
        {
          width:450px;
          height:578px;
          background-image: url('sheep.jpg');
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: 320px;
          position: absolute;
          top:380px;
          left:451px;
          background-color:#cbb;
         }   

     #box6
         {
          width:450px;
          height:470px;
          background-image: url('sheep.jpg');
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: 320px;
          position: absolute;
          top:195px;
          left:901px;
          background-color:#ad9;    
         }

     #box7
         {
          width:450px;
          height:298px;
          background-image: url('sheep.jpg');
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: 320px;
          position: absolute;
          top:660px;
          left:901px;
          background-color:#d8f;
         }
```