# Scaffolding... Masonry... columns in Bootstrap? (no-JS, no-CSS3)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, scaffolding, masonry, dynamic-columns

I've been fiddling with this issue for almost 8 hours and I gave up...

Check the images; my client wants a Bootstrap-grid that has two columns (or at least they must look like columns).

On bigger screens, you see two columns - contain DIV's with different (and dynamic) height.

**[big screen - two columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHIvP.png)**

On a small screen, the columns must disappear and the DIV's must be placed from "A" to "Z" (well... "F" actually).

**[small screen - no columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiVpm.png)**

How it this technique called? Or how can I get this done, using Bootstrap 3 - but without CSS3 (Android 4 must support it) or JS / jQuery?

I've been playing around with the pull-left / col-md-push-6 / etc... classes, but the biggest problem is that each DIV has a different height and you never know what the height is.

Comment: how can we re-code seeing just your picture?

Comment: I understand your question, but none of my codes are working in the way I want... So I want to start from scratch; even without Bootstrap when needed... I am even not sure this layout can be done, without JS...

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470070/how-to-create-grid-tile-view-with-css. Simply, even flexbox can't do **exactly** what the OP requires.

Comment: If it can't be done using regular CSS, I'll tell my client so... Maybe I can force him to use the Mansonry-script; but I don't like the idea to use scripting for styling (from a pure developers point of view, that is...).

Comment: For those who are interested; I came up with this; http://jsfiddle.net/Lf8jojb4/9/ (not my code - but with a little help from a friend). Just resize the preview-pane to see the script in action.