# make divs of different heights fill vertical space on new line

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a grid which should look something like this

[what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABNwM.jpg)

but it renders as this

[what it actually looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU08B.png)

here is my HTML code

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap">
    <div class="item" style="height: 400px; background-color: #ddd"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 200px; background-color: #000"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 200px; background-color: #ececec"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 700px; background-color: #DC0F0F"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 400px; background-color: #B429A2"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 200px; background-color: #009EBA"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 200px; background-color: #694141"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 400px; background-color: #29B436"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 200px; background-color: #74B2BD"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 700px; background-color: #DCDA0F"></div>
</div>
```

The item class has a static width: 33%.

I understand that doing something like this in JS is quite possible. But I am looking for a pure CSS solution.

Thanks

Comment: You can't make rows behave like columns...even with flexbox. If you want columns...use columns.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470070/how-to-create-grid-tile-view-with-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option is to use [`Masonry`](http://masonry.desandro.com/) but if you insist on CSS only solution then you should use [`columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns)
Here is **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/411/)**

```css
.wrapper {
 -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
  column-count: 3;
 -webkit-column-gap: 0; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 -moz-column-gap: 0; /* Firefox */
  column-gap: 0;
  width: 100vw;
}

.wrapper div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;

}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item" style="height: 400px; background-color: #ddd"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 200px; background-color: #000"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 200px; background-color: #ececec"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 700px; background-color: #DC0F0F"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 400px; background-color: #B429A2"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 200px; background-color: #009EBA"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 200px; background-color: #694141"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 400px; background-color: #29B436"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 200px; background-color: #74B2BD"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 700px; background-color: #DCDA0F"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: your CSS solution works perfectly. So why do you insist on Masonry?

Comment: `:)` i don't insist on Masonry but i think its better solution since it's built for this exact purpose, also support on css columns is like this http://caniuse.com/#search=column.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `flex-direction` and `align-content` properties to your wrapper element. and some fixed height....
Check the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ronency/zr6ppnym/)

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  height: 1400px;
  display: flex; 
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.item {
  width:33%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item" style="height: 300px; background-color: #ddd"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 200px; background-color: #000"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 200px; background-color: #ececec"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 700px; background-color: #DC0F0F"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 400px; background-color: #B429A2"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 200px; background-color: #009EBA"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 200px; background-color: #694141"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 400px; background-color: #29B436"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 200px; background-color: #74B2BD"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 700px; background-color: #DCDA0F"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a few more flex properties fixed it. I added:

```
flex-direction: column;
align-content: flex-start;
```

might not be exactly what you need but you should be able to adjust it to your needs


## See the JS Fiddle


[CSS Tricks guide to flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score -1):

```
<div style="display: flex; width: 100%;">
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 33%;">
    <div class="item" style="height: 400px; background-color: #ddd"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 700px; background-color: #DC0F0F"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 33%;">
    <div class="item" style="height: 200px; background-color: #000"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 400px; background-color: #B429A2"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 400px; background-color: #29B436"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 33%;">
    <div class="item" style="height: 200px; background-color: #ececec"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 200px; background-color: #009EBA"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 200px; background-color: #74B2BD"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 200px; background-color: #694141"></div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 700px; background-color: #DCDA0F"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no explanation, And it doesn't answer the PO request :-)