# Fluidly float div left

Tags: css, css-float, flexbox

Here's a image of what i'm trying to do vs what i'm getting

[image]

Basically i'm floating all the div left  but because the first div's height is taller than the rest, its leaving a gaping hole.

The generated divs are products in a shop collection.
while the tall first div is a filter menu that's always present.

How do i get all the div to fluidly float left and fill in the empty space.
Should i be looking at flex box? And its NOT a masonry / isotope kind of layout. only the first div has a taller height

here the page im working on:
http://goo.gl/4LfgAx

Comment: Could you please add a fiddle demo ?.

Comment: the live example http://goo.gl/4LfgAx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34481128/3597276

Comment: how come its possible here: https://jsfiddle.net/880e3r53/

Comment: Your question asked if the layout was possible with flexbox. The link I posted explains why it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```css
div.container{
  width: 250px !important;
  border: none;
}
div.container div.row{
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
}

div.container div.row div{
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3" style="height: 100px;"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```