# Using flexbox to create responsive image grid with various sizes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a design based on flexbox with an aspect ratio of 16:9. I want to create a design similar to the attached image, but i am not sure how to create the last column. Furthermore i would like to introduce responsive behavior into the design.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVdLJv

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex_container">
  <div class="flex_group__1">
    <img src="holder.js/460x670" />
    <img src="holder.js/460x408" />
  </div>
  <div class="flex_group__2">
    <img src="holder.js/645x813">
    <img src="holder.js/645x265">
  </div>
  <div class="flex_group__3">
    <img src="holder.js/808x330"/>
    <img src="holder.js/452x748"/>
    <img src="holder.js/356x748"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flex_group__1, .flex_group__2, .flex_group__3, .flex_container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex_container {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex_group__3 {
  flex-direction: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.flex_group__1, .flex_group__2 {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I modified my answer some, and added a link to an updated codepen

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34481128/3597276

Comment: I tried with isotope and masonry, but it was just way too cumbersome to get working, so i gave up and went with this which may seem very static (which it is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add another flex group in `flex_group__3`

Updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VabMwm)

Note, the `flex_group__3` needs to be `column`

CSS (rules updated)

```
.flex_group__1, .flex_group__2, .flex_group__3, .flex_group__3_inner_bottom, .flex_container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex_group__1, .flex_group__2, .flex_group__3 {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

HTML (markup updated/added)

```
<div class="flex_group__3">
  <img src="holder.js/808x330"/>
  <div class="flex_group__3_inner_bottom">
    <img src="holder.js/452x748"/>
    <img src="holder.js/356x748"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That makes so much sense. The only dilemma is how to deal with the responsiveness.

Comment: @JavaCake Two ways, as I see it, media queries or give the images a max width which corresponds the their size in relation to the total size of the flex container.

Comment: I was hoping i could set it to 100% width and make the page adjust it accordingly, but it seems to be way more complicated than what i though initially.

Comment: @JavaCake Nothing is that simple :) .. almost anyway .. This is a trial and error project, though I would start with giving the items an proportional size in relation to the layout's size. Happy holiday :)

Comment: Well i am thinking if masonry is a better way to go or not.. I have no clue how to resize this without too much spaghetti code.

Comment: @JavaCake I made some adjustments to this codepen, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VabMwm, where I added some rules in the end ... hope this help what to chose :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107163/discussion-between-javacake-and-lgson).

Comment: Heres my attempt to fix the responsiveness hence i am already working with bootstrap: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGmpvX

Comment: @JavaCake Then I take my hands out of the cookie jar, as bootstrap is no friend of mine :)

Comment: Well bootstrap does nothing for me to be honest. Except for the media queries.

Answer (score 0):

So, this was driving me a bit bonkers, so I had at it. You can also see my results on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/angeliquejw/pen/BKRYVq?editors=0100). There's a lot of containers inside of containers here, which is meant to duplicate this exact layout and will likely not be great for anything else, but I've gotten close and it's responsive. (Only two media queries in there, but you could do additional ones.)

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
.flex_container {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.flex_container > .flex_group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex_container > .flex_group:first-child {
  width: 460px;
}
.flex_container > .flex_group:nth-child(2) {
  width: 645px;
}
.flex_container > .flex_group:nth-child(3) {
  width: 808px;
}
.flex_group img {
  padding: 10px;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.flex_group > .flex_group:last-child img:first-child {
  width: 50%;
}
.flex_group > .flex_group:last-child img:last-child {
  width: 50%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 399px) {
  .flex_group > .flex_group:last-child img {
    width: 100%!important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 599px) {
  .flex_container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
/* fallback for earlier versions of Firefox */

@supports not (flex-wrap: wrap) {
  .flex_container {
    display: block;
  }
  .flex_container img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex_container">
  <div class="flex_group">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/460x670" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/460x408" />
  </div>
  <div class="flex_group">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/645x813">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/645x265">

  </div>
  <div class="flex_group">
    <div class="flex_group">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/808x330" />
    </div>
    <div class="flex_group">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/404x748" />
      <img src="http://placehold.it/404x748" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```