# Is it possible to mix rows and columns with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In other words, is it possible to achieve this?

[image]

*Note:* This is the best I could get:

```css
html, body, .container {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #ececec;
  flex: 1;
}

.container > div:nth-of-type(1) {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}

.container>div:nth-of-type(4) {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Div 1</div>
  <div>Div 2</div>
  <div>Div 3</div>
  <div>Div 4</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kzbbb/249/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can achieve the layout with a few nested flexboxes. Here's the result of the code below:

[image]

```css
html, body, .container {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;       
    /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
}

.container div {                   
    margin: 10px;
    flex: 1;
    background-color: orange;
}

.container > div:first-child { }

.container > div:nth-child(2) {
    display: flex;
    background-color: white;
}

.container > div:nth-child(2) > div:first-child {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: white;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.container > div:nth-child(2) div {
    flex: 1;
    margin: 0;
}

.container > div:nth-child(2) > div:first-child > div:first-child {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.container > div:last-child { }
```

```html
<div class="container">                <!-- flex container -->

    <div>Div 1</div>                   <!-- flex item #1 -->
    
    <div>                              <!-- flex item #2 and nested flex container -->
    
        <div>                          <!-- flex item and nested flex container -->
        
            <div>Div 2.1.1</div>       <!-- flex item -->
            
            <div>Div 2.1.2</div>       <!-- flex item -->

        </div>                         <!-- end flex item / container 2.1 -->
        
        <div>Div 2.2</div>             <!-- flex item -->
        
    </div>                             <!-- end flex item / container #2 -->
    
  <div>Div 3</div>                     <!-- flex item #3 -->
  
</div>                                 <!-- end .container -->
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kzbbb/252/)

Comment: This answer would have been much more effective had you commented the CSS or assigned discernible classes.

Comment: Maybe so. Here's another answer to a similar question that may be more useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34481128/3597276 @EternalHour

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve what you want just make two changes to your code

**First:** 
Those divs that that you want one under the other, make them as child of a div as

```
<div class="container">
  <div>Div 1</div>
  <div>
    <div>Div 2</div>
    <div>Div 3</div>
  </div>
  <div>Div 4</div>
  <div>Div 5</div>
</div>
```

**Second:** In order to create a border for all div write your css as

```
.container  div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #ececec;
  flex: 1;
}
```

instead of

```
.container > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #ececec;
  flex: 1;
}
```

which will apply the styles to all `divs` instead of `divs` directly inside the `.container` class

Have a look at this:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container  div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #ececec;
  flex: 1;
}

.container > div:nth-of-type(1) {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}

.container > div:nth-of-type(4) {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Div 1</div>
  <div>
    <div>Div 2</div>
    <div>Div 3</div>
  </div>
  <div>Div 4</div>
  <div>Div 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with nested flexbox, and you don't need to wrap at all.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container > div {
  background: #ececec;
  flex: 1;
}
.container > div:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: flex;
}
.container > div:nth-of-type(2) > div {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container > div:nth-of-type(2) > div > div {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Div 1</div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>Div 2.1 A</div>
      <div>Div 2.1 B</div>
    </div>
    <div>Div 2.2</div>
  </div>
  <div>Div 3</div>
</div>
```