# Using flexbox to push smaller sized items to the right of the container

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm using flexbox to create a responsive design and I have it working for a smaller width, so I'm keen to keep this layout and am just overwriting certain parts to get a different layout.

In my [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/L1w6qkyu/1/), you can see I have a `.featured` article (orange) which sits to the left of the viewport. I then have a number of smaller articles which I want to have sitting on the right of `.featured`

Using `display:flex;` with `flex-wrap:wrap;` gets the first item to sit to the right, but the subsequent green boxes all sit below. It seems my first green `article` is getting the full height of the row that it sits on.

How can I tidy up this layout to get the green articles to sit to the right?

```
.summaries {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align:right;

  article {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: 24px;
    width: calc(60% - 24px);
  }
}

article {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  &.featured {
    height: 500px;
    flex: 0 0 calc(40% - 24px);
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 24px;
    background-color: orange;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's working as expected...that's the way wrapping works. You would have to wrap the green articles in their own column wrapper.

Comment: @Paulie_D I understand it's working as expected, but I'm looking for advice on adjustments to make this layout work. I can't add more HTML so I cannot add a column to the other items.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34480760/3597276

Comment: The you may have to resort to Javascript to do the wrapping for you.

Comment: ...and if you are "creating a responsive design" then why can't you change the HTML...isn't that the point of designing it?