# Flexbox layout where shorter items wrap underneath each other?

Tags: css, flexbox

Is it possible to make this layout where the only markup is items within a single container? Im assuming flexbox is required.

[image]

```
<div class="cont">
  <div class="item item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item item-2">2 <br> wrap</div>
  <div class="item item-3">3</div>
  <div class="item item-4">4</div>
  <div class="item item-5">5</div>
  <div class="item item-6">6</div>
  <div class="item item-7">7</div>
</div>

.cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.item-1 {
  background: blue;
  order: 1;
}

.item-2 {
  background: green;
  order: 2;
}

.item-3 {
  background: yellow;
  order: 3;
}

.item-4 {
  background: teal;
  order: 4;
}

.item-5 {
  background: grey;
  order: 5;
}

.item-6 {
  background: orange;
  order: 6;
}

.item-7 {
  background: gold;
  order: 7;
}

.item-1,
.item-2,
.item-3 {
  width: 50%;
}

.item-4,
.item-5,
.item-6,
.item-7 {
  width: 25%;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NAvXrz

Comment: Do you want to set fixed height on `container`?

Comment: No I cant do this as the content is dynamic. Also the layout is responsive, so the widths must be a %.

Comment: You would need to adjust the mark-up to wrap items 2 and 3 in their own container. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34481128/3597276

Comment: No, this is not possible with flexbox