# Calculator keypad layout with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am building a calculator with flexbox. I want one of its keys twice the height and another key twice the width.

I googled much about it but couldn't find both cases together.

For twice height key, only answers I found was to make `flex-direction` as `column`. But in that case I will not be able to make double width key.

Here is [my code](https://codepen.io/suyashgulati/pen/mEYEzm) (on codepen.io). Please help.

```js
$(function() {
  var curr = "",
    prev = "";
  var updateView = function() {
    $('#curr').html(curr);
    $('#prev').html(prev);
  };
  $('.keysNum').on('click', function(e) {
    curr += $(this).html();
    console.log(this);
    updateView();
  });
  $('.keysOp').on('click', function(e) {

  });
});
```

```css
.flexBoxContainer {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.calculator {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

@media (min-width: 321px) {
  .calculator {
    width: 320px;
  }
}

.calculator .keys {
  border: #d3d2cb 0.5px solid;
  background: #fefdff;
  color: #33393d;
  height: 50px;
  height: 14.2857142857vh;
  width: 25%;
  line-height: 14.2857142857vh;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: background 0.2s linear;
}

.calculator .keysOp {
  background: #f1f1ef;
}

.calculator .keysC {
  color: #f94913;
}

.calculator .keys:hover {
  background: #d3d2cb;
  transition: background 0s linear;
}

.calculator .keys:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.calculator .keys:active {
  background: #93938E;
}

.calculator .screen {
  background: #e9e8e5;
  height: 14.2857142857vh;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 14.2857142857vh;
  direction: rtl;
}

.calculator .screen:last-child {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.calculator #anomaly-keys-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.calculator #anomaly-keys-wrapper>section:first-child {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 75%;
}

.calculator #anomaly-keys-wrapper>section:first-child>div.keys {
  flex: 1 0 33.33%;
}

.calculator #anomaly-keys-wrapper>section:first-child>div.long {
  flex-basis: 66.67%;
}

.calculator #anomaly-keys-wrapper>section:last-child {
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.calculator #anomaly-keys-wrapper>section:last-child>.tall {
  background: #f94913;
  color: #fefdff;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 28.5714285714vh;
  flex: 1;
}

.calculator #anomaly-keys-wrapper>section:last-child>.tall:hover {
  background: #c73a0f;
}

.calculator #anomaly-keys-wrapper>section:last-child>.tall:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.calculator #anomaly-keys-wrapper>section:last-child>.tall:active {
  background: #8b280a;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flexBoxContainer">
  <div class="calculator">
    <div class="screen" id="prev"></div>
    <div class="screen" id="curr"></div>
    <!--     <div class="keys keysC keysOp" tabindex="2">C</div> -->
    <div class="keys keysC keysOp" tabindex="2">C</div>
    <div class="keys keysOp" tabindex="3"><i class="icon ion-backspace-outline"></i></div>
    <div class="keys keysOp" tabindex="4">&divide</div>
    <div class="keys keysOp" tabindex="5">&times</div>
    <div class="keys keysNum" tabindex="6">7</div>
    <div class="keys keysNum" tabindex="7">8</div>
    <div class="keys keysNum" tabindex="8">9</div>
    <div class="keys keysOp" tabindex="9">-</div>
    <div class="keys keysNum" tabindex="10">4</div>
    <div class="keys keysNum" tabindex="11">5</div>
    <div class="keys keysNum" tabindex="12">6</div>
    <div class="keys keysOp" tabindex="13">+</div>
    <section id="anomaly-keys-wrapper">
      <section>
        <div class="keys keysNum" tabindex="14">1</div>
        <div class="keys keysNum" tabindex="15">2</div>
        <div class="keys keysNum" tabindex="16">3</div>
        <div class="keys long keysNum" tabindex="17">0</div>
        <div class="keys" tabindex="18">.</div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div class="keys tall" tabindex="19">=</div>
      </section>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the uneven keys in their own flex containers and go from there...

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }                                      /* 1 */

.flexBoxContainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.calculator {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.calculator .keys {
    border: red 1px solid;
    height: 50px;
    width: 25%;
    break-inside: avoid;
}

.calculator input {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    direction: rtl;
}

#anomaly-keys-wrapper {                                            /* 2 */
    display: flex;
    width: 100%; 
}

#anomaly-keys-wrapper > section:first-child {                      /* 3 */
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 75%;
}

#anomaly-keys-wrapper > section:first-child > div {                /* 4 */
    flex: 1 0 33.33%;
}

#anomaly-keys-wrapper > section:first-child > div:nth-child(4) {   /* 5 */
    flex-basis: 66.67%;
}

#anomaly-keys-wrapper > section:last-child {                       /* 6 */
    width: 25%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#anomaly-keys-wrapper .tall {                                      /* 7 */
    width: 100%;
    flex: 1;
}

@media (min-width: 321px) {
    .calculator {
        width: 320px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="flexBoxContainer">
    <div class="calculator">
        <input />
        <div class="keys"></div>
        <div class="keys"></div>
        <div class="keys"></div>
        <div class="keys"></div>
        <div class="keys"></div>
        <div class="keys"></div>
        <div class="keys"></div>
        <div class="keys"></div>
        <div class="keys"></div>
        <div class="keys"></div>
        <div class="keys"></div>
        <div class="keys"></div>
        <section id="anomaly-keys-wrapper">
            <section>
                <div class="keys"></div>
                <div class="keys"></div>
                <div class="keys"></div>
                <div class="keys long"></div>
                <div class="keys"></div>
            </section>
            <section>
                <div class="keys tall"></div>
            </section>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Revised Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vKwykr) (with compiled CSS)

Notes:

1. Include padding and borders in `width` / `height` calculations.
2. Wrap uneven keys in a separate flex container (with defaults `flex-direction: row` and `flex-wrap: nowrap`)
3. Wrap *long* key in a separate flex container with wrapping enabled (and take enough siblings to create equal height with *tall* key).
4. Force three keys per row max.
5. Make *long* key twice the width of siblings. (Didn't use simpler `long` class selector due to weaker specificity.)
6. Wrap *tall* key in a separate flex container with vertical orientation.
7. Make *tall* key consume all available width and height of container.

---

**UPDATE**

*From the comments:*

> Hi, 1. Can you explain me how flex basis works? and why did you use it instead of giving width to long button. 2. Why is it necessary to give flex: 1; to tall button, as i have read it is the default value.

**Question #1:**

The keys in the first sub-section container (containing `.long`) are sized with `flex: 1 0 33.33%`.

This is shorthand for `flex-grow: 1`, `flex-shrink: 0`, and `flex-basis: 33.33%`.

For the `.long` key we are simply overriding the `flex-basis` component with `66.67%`. (there's no need to re-declare the other two components).

Also, there's really no difference in this case between `width` and `flex-basis`, but since we're overriding `flex-basis`, I used `flex-basis`.

Using `width` would leave the original `flex-basis: 33.33%` intact, creating two `width` rules which may, therefore, fail to expand the `.long` key, depending on which rule prevails in the cascade.

For a complete explanation of `flex-basis` vs. `width`, see **[What are the differences between flex-basis and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276)**

**Question #2:**

Because the initial value of the `flex-grow` component is `0` ([source](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-grow-property)).

Comment: Hi,

1. Can you explain me how flex basis works?
and why did you use it instead of giving width to long button.

2. Why is it necessary to give `flex: 1;` to tall button, as i have read it is the default value.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a response to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a generic answer I can come up with, but this is as close as I can get.

I have modified your code to use floating instead of the flexbox layout model. This is less modern, but seems to be a viable workaround to this particular problem, with little to no negative effects.

> Please note that I have also modified the `width` of the buttons to actually take up all the space they can, and gave them a `box-sizing` of `border-box`. More on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VjOKGX

```
.calculator {
    // Required to keep the buttons inside
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    @media #{$gtphone} {
        width: 320px;
    }
    .keys {
        // Changes the box model so that width includes the borders too
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: red 1px solid;
        height: 50px;
        // The width is modified to take up all the space
        width: 25%;
        // Floating is defined
        float: left;
        break-inside: avoid;
    }
    .long {
        // This one needs float to be set to right,
        // so that other elements may be on its left in multiple rows
        float: right;
        height: 100px !important;
    }
    .big {
        // Again, width is modified
        width: 50% !important;
    }
    input {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        direction: rtl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you prompt reply, but i was looking for a solution with flexbox only, as i am in a learning mode right now.
I might use your method probably in future as it was easier and small code.