# CSS Flex: Display like rowspan and colspan

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to build something in CSS and I'm hitting a bug.

I have a few elements in my flex that need to be double width and double height compared to the rest of the elements.

See example here of what I got right now. http://jsfiddle.net/pJy66/25/

I'd like to display it like this

```
(1)(2)(3)(3)
(4)(5)(3)(3)
(6)(6)(7)(8)
(6)(6)(9)(0)
```

But as you can see in the fiddle, it seems to clear the elements so it shows like this

```
(1)(2)(3)(3)
( )( )(3)(3)
(4)(5)(6)(7)
(8)(8)(9)(0)
(8)(8)( )( )
```

So can I do some kind of a rowspan to have the 4-5 elements on the left of element 3?

```css
.foo {
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.foo div{
  background:#888;
  width:25%;
  height:50px;
}

.foo .b1{background:#000;}
.foo .b2{background:#555;}
.foo .b3{background:#111;}
.foo .b4{background:#666;}
.foo .b5{background:#222;}
.foo .b6{background:#777;}
.foo .b7{background:#333;}
.foo .b8{background:#888;}
.foo .b9{background:#444;}
.foo .b10{background:#999;}

.foo .b1, .foo .b8{
  height:100px;
  width:50%
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <div class="b1"></div>
  <div class="b2"></div>
  <div class="b3"></div>
  <div class="b4"></div>
  <div class="b5"></div>
  <div class="b6"></div>
  <div class="b7"></div>
  <div class="b8"></div>
  <div class="b9"></div>
  <div class="b10"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope, flexbox does not do well for stuff like that, you need grid or a table ... or a script

Comment: for the googlers - another solution might be based on http://www.java2s.com/example/html-css/css-layout/rowspan-behavior-with-flexbox.html [still wrokking on the exact solution for this question, though]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to nest flex containers, i.e. define some of the flex-items (children) to be flex-containers (parents) themselves.

In your example...

```
(1)(2)(3)(3)
(4)(5)(3)(3)
(6)(6)(7)(8)
(6)(6)(9)(0)
```

... 1,2,4,5 and 7,8,9,0 would be nested in flex-items A and B,
so the outer structure would be

```
A 3
6 B
```

..., where inside that, A would consist of

```
1 2
4 5
```

...and B would consist of

```
7 8
9 0
```

The overall container, A and B would have `display: flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap`, with appropriate width and `flex` settings for the smaller elements.

Comment: yup exactly I forgot in an eyeblink about the row stuff. Thx

Answer (score 4):

Break the main container into four groups, then use nested containers where necessary.

```css
.foo {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.foo > div {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.group1 > div, .group4 > div {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  height: 50px;
}

.foo .b1  { background: #000;  }
.foo .b2  { background: #555;  }
.foo .b3  { background: green; }
.foo .b4  { background: #666;  }
.foo .b5  { background: #222;  }
.foo .b6  { background: red;   }
.foo .b7  { background: #333;  }
.foo .b8  { background: #888;  }
.foo .b9  { background: #444;  }
.foo .b10 { background: #999;  }
```

```html
<div class="foo">

  <div class="group1">
    <div class="b1">1</div>
    <div class="b2">2</div>
    <div class="b4">4</div>
    <div class="b5">5</div>
  </div>

  <div class="group2 b3">3</div>

  <div class="group3 b6">6</div>

  <div class="group4">
    <div class="b7">7</div>
    <div class="b8">8</div>
    <div class="b9">9</div>
    <div class="b10">10</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pJy66/27/)

Here's something similar I did for a calculator keypad layout:

- [Calculator keypad layout with flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39079773/3597276)

Comment: Sadly doesnt really fix the problem, I can't break the 3 and 6 elements in 4 parts. They should stay whole.

Comment: Yes, I realized that I made a mistake. You want double height also. I'm working on the correction.

Comment: that's what i wrote in my answer (without detailed code, but still)... ;-)

Comment: @Johannes, I didn't see your answer. Was on jsfiddle building this thing. Anyway, if you want, complete your answer with code (you can use mine if you want), and I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @Michael_B why? we have yours :)

Comment: no no, not necessary. I know you as "Master of Flexboxes" - I am just wondering that you weren't faster than I was... ;-) (+1 for your code)

Comment: @Johannes If you look at the edit history, I misread the question originally and gave an incorrect answer. Then I got distracted with something else. Then I came back to make the correction later. If you were first with the answer, just add the code. I don't mind. Cheers!