# gallery style layout with css flex-box?

Tags: css, flexbox

How can I do this sort of a gallery style layout with flex box?

I have a `<ul>` with `<li>` in them. The first `<li>` I want to be double size and have the rest of the items flow around it.[image]

I can layout the items using flexbox with the following code, but when I go double size on the first item I can't figure out how to reflow the boxes to fit around it as pictured.

```
ul, li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    list-style-type: none;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
}

ul > li {
    width: 15rem;
    height: 15rem;
    order: 2;
}

ul > li.active {
    width: 30rem;
    height: 30rem;
    order: 1;
}
```

I have some javascript that cycles through the `<li>` tags and adds the `.active` class. Using `order: 1` I can move the currently active image to the first spot (the double-sized version).

Comment: Maybe it will help you. I always use this if I have problems with felxbox. Now I have no time to write answer: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: You can't reflow flex items like that in a proper way. If you tell what should happen on smaller screen widths we can provide a good answer

Comment: Do really need to use flex? you can achieve this otherwise too.

Comment: related: [Make a calculator keypad layout with flexbox](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39079773/3597276)

Answer (score -2):

I don' really know about flex, but you can do this with 'float'

```
ul, li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
}

ul > li {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    float: left
}

ul li:nth-child(1) {
    width: calc( 50px * 2 + 5px);
    height: calc( 50px * 2 + 5px);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vcqp8an6/

Comment: float is like tables now. Learn flex.

Comment: I did use flex in some case if there's an opportunity, but if you're stucked with client that insist older IE support, then no choice.

Comment: I think float has many problems , (in the siblings) and lot of clearance is needed ,
also it does not meant for alignment, where flex does, so just go and learn flex