# What's the best way to achieve this layout with flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

I have 4 columns and three rows. The last tile is two rows high.[image]

I'm working on a code that looks like this:

```
.gridContainer {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.gridItems {
 width: 290px;
 height: 350px;
 margin: 0 5px 10px;
 border-radius: 4px;
}

.gridItemsTall {
  width: 290px;
  height: 710px;
  margin: 0 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: [Calculator keypad layout with flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39079773/3597276)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to achieve this with flexbox it's by using a combinaison of `flex-direction: column`, `flex-wrap: wrap` and `max-height`.

He is an update of your CSS :

```
.gridContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
 max-height: 1080px; // box height *3 + margin-bottom*3 -> 350*3 + 10*3 
}

.gridItems {
  width: 290px;
  height: 350px;
  margin: 0 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.gridItemsTall {
  height: 710px;
}
```

And on the following link, you can find a live example : https://jsfiddle.net/julienvanderkluft/dkdfy7gb/

Note that the height of `.gridContainer` can be manipulate by JavaScript for more flexibility.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS Grid layout instead of flexbox in this case. You just need to set `grid-row: span 2` on element you want to take two rows.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}

.box {
  background: #aaa;
}

.large {
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box large"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```