# wrap div around other divs avoiding space in between

Tags: html, css

I have divs with class .block which has the following css:

```
.block {
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 0;
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 10px;
    min-width: 220px;
    max-width: 300px;
    min-height: 200px;
    max-height: 400px;
    font-size: 17pt;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #888888;
    border-radius: 10px;
    word-break:break-all;
}
```

And this is what the page currently looks like:

[image]

But I want it to wrap and go to the top with the other divs like so:

[image]

How can something like this be achieved?

Comment: google -> mansory.js

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34480760/3597276

Comment: Here a nice way to achieve it it's called masonry http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/myBxD

Comment: I'm sorry about the duplicate guys, thanks so much for the help!

Comment: The title of the dupe is misleading, as the answers all involve JavaScript.