# How to make a flex-box gallery with items of different size?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I am trying to make something similar like the image below (first half) with flex boxes (Bootstrap 4).

[image]

However, as you can see in the second part of the image above and in the code (expand the snippet please) I cannot push the green square (number) 4 under number 1 (Red) and between number 2 (yellow) as the picture is showing. I mean, there is a gap between the red square and the green one and I want to delete it.

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">



</head>

<body>

  <!--main-->
  <div class="container">
    <!--projects-->
    <div style="background-color:PINK" class="col-12">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap ">

          <div style="background-color: red; width: 370px; height: 258px; padding: 1.5rem; ">1</div>
          <div style="background-color: yellow; width: 370px; height: 516px; padding: 1.5rem; ">2</div>
          <div style="background-color: blue; width: 370px; height: 258px; padding: 1.5rem; ">3</div>
          <div style="background-color: green;  width: 370px; height: 258px; padding: 1.5rem; ">4</div>
          <div style="background-color: orange; width: 370px; height: 516px; padding: 1.5rem;">5</div>
          <div style="background-color: white;  width: 370px; height: 258px; padding: 1.5rem;">6</div>
          <div style="background-color: paleturquoise;  width: 370px; height: 258px; padding: 1.5rem;">7</div>
          <div style="background-color: purple;  width: 370px; height: 258px; padding: 1.5rem;">8</div>
          <div style="background-color: mediumaquamarine;  width: 370px; height: 258px; padding: 1.5rem;">9</div>
          <div style="background-color: mediumslateblue;  width: 370px; height: 258px; padding: 1.5rem;">10</div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <body>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D why is it duplicate??? Could you tell me where is the other post?

Comment: The "other" post is linked at the top of your question.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34480760/3597276

Answer (score 0):

For this design to work with flex-box you'd have to group 1, 4, 6, 8 in one flex box column. AFAIK it's not possible with flex box to achieve the results you're looking for without more than one container element.