# Alternatives for extra containers in a flexbox grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have two `.flex-container` with 3 `.box` children that I want to set up differently. See my snippet for a visual and my solution.

The first is easy as I can set the first box to be `width: 100%;` and then just use `flex-wrap: wrap;`. Good to go.

For the second `.flex-container` I found I had to add an extra container `.box-container` around the last two boxes and then give it `flex: auto;` to get the desired effect.

My question is do I need this extra container `.box-container`? If the answer is yes, so be it. I feel like I am missing something fundamental, but I'm thinking it could require it because these layouts aren't height-based and I guess it's vertically oriented? I tried using `flex-direction: column;` in different ways.

Any solution using flexbox and no extra containers, like the first layout I presented, would be much appreciated. Thank you.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.flex-container-1 {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 3px solid seagreen;
  background-color: mediumseagreen;
}

.flex-container-1 .box:first-of-type {
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-container-2 {
  border: 3px solid firebrick;
  background-color: indianred;
}

.box-container {
  flex: auto;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.box .box-num {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-container-1">
  <div class="box">
    <span class="box-num">1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <span class="box-num">2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <span class="box-num">3</span>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="flex-container-2">
  <div class="box">
    <span class="box-num">1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box-container">
    <div class="box">
      <span class="box-num">2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <span class="box-num">3</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: If you can set a fixed height on the container, then the second example can be achieved using the same method as the first, except with `column wrap`. If not, then you need a nested container for items 2 & 3.

Comment: If you don't care about IE / Edge support, then CSS Grid Layout can handle this easily.

Comment: Thanks Michael that's the answer I needed. Also +1 I never think to use flex-flow until now. Makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Flex Layout

You cannot make flex items wrap under other items in the same row. That's just not how flexbox works, which is along horizontal and vertical lines. So to stack two items next to one in the same "row", you'll need a bit of CSS or HTML trickery.

You can either:

- Define a height on the container. This will enable you to use `flex-flow: column wrap` to stack items 2 and 3 next to item 1 as two equal height columns, otherwise...
- Use a nested container. This will allow you to wrap items 2 and 3 in one item which can become a sibling of item 1, and both columns can have equal height.

These concepts and their limitations are further explained in my answer here:

- [Is it possible for flex items to align tightly to the items above them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34480760/3597276)

---

### Grid Layout

Because [**CSS Grid Layout**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/) is now supported by most major browsers, and because your layout objective is simple with this new technology, and because with Grid Layout ***you'll never need to wrap items in nested containers or set a fixed height on the main container***, I've posted an answer below:

```css
article {
  display: grid;                            /* 1 */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);    /* 2 */
}

section:nth-child(1) {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;                          /* 3 */
}

/* non-essential decorative styles */

article {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 3px solid firebrick;
  background-color: indianred;
}
section {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<article>
    <section>1</section>
    <section>2</section>
    <section>3</section>
</article>
```

Notes:

1. Establish block-level grid container. ([spec reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-containers))
2. Instruct the grid to create two equal width columns. `1fr` represents a proportion of free space. It's similar to `flex-grow: 1`. ([spec reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#repeat-notation))
3. Instruct the first item to span two rows (i.e., from grid row line 1 to grid row line 3, which covers two grid tracks). ([spec reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#placement-shorthands))

**Browser Support for CSS Grid**

- Chrome - full support as of March 8, 2017 (version 57)
- Firefox - full support as of March 6, 2017 (version 52)
- Safari - full support as of March 26, 2017 (version 10.1)
- Edge - full support as of October 16, 2017 (version 16)
- IE11 - no support for current spec; supports obsolete version

Here's the complete picture: http://caniuse.com/#search=grid

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Unless I use a fixed height on the container.