# Two column flexbox layout with fixed div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm attempting to learn flexbox and I'm trying to achieve the following layout.

```
+----------+----------+
|          |nav       |
|  header  +----------+
|          |section   |
+----------+----------+
```

HTML Structure

```
<header></header>
<nav></nav>
<section></section>
```

Layout Requirements

1. Width of each element is exactly 50vw (or 50%)
2. Header content is always centered and fixed. Takes up 100vh.
3. Nav content is fixed
4. Section content is scrollable, overflow is hidden.

Is this even possible with flexbox?

On mobile devices, I want to have all three in a column but that part is easy.

Comment: If you can set a fixed height on the container, then your layout is possible with flexbox using `column wrap`. If you can't set a height, then you need to wrap the `nav` and `section` elements in a nested container. If you can't do that, then NO, it's not possible with flexbox...

Comment: Are you able to use CSS Grid Layout?

Comment: I could set the container to 100vh I guess. I don't want to wrap nav and section into a nested container if possible, so I don't complicate mobile styling. CSS Grid layout will not work, I need some backward compatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 100vh; /* key rule; this tells flex items where to wrap
                    to form second column */
}

header {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  width: 50%;

  /* center content */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

nav, section {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  width: 50%;
}

/* non-essential decorative styles */
*       { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; }
header  { background-color: aqua; }
nav     { background-color: tomato; }
section { background-color: lightgreen; }
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<nav>nav</nav>
<section>section</section>
```

For a detailed explanation and alternative methods see my answer here:

- [Is it possible for flex items to align tightly to the items above them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34480760/3597276)

Comment: Thank you, this almost solves my problem :-) I have two issues with it and I don't see a good solution yet. I'm going through some flexbox tutorials maybe I'll see the solution. The problem I have is I want the nave to have a fixed height, sorry, I did not make that clear in my question. Also when I have overflowing content in the section div, the entire div just disappears.

Comment: The overflow problem I think can be fixed. But overall, flexbox is not designed to build perfect grids, because flex items can span columns *or* rows, but not both. That's why CSS Grid is perfect for this, but I understand you can't use it. See the link I posted at the end of my answer for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use flexbox you can get away with doing a dual container layout.

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex-container">
<header>Something</header>
<div class="flex-child-container">
<nav>nav</nav>
<section>section</section>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
display: flex;
width: 100%;
height: 100%
}

.flex-child-container {
flex-direction: column;
}
```