# Flexbox vs CSS Grid real world example

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I have read a few posts that say -Flexbox should be used for small scale layout and CSS grid should be used for large layout. e.g.

[Don't use flexbox for overall page layout - JakeArchibald.com](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/dont-use-flexbox-for-page-layout/)

[Should I use Grid or Flexbox? - rachelandrew.co.uk](https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/03/30/should-i-use-grid-or-flexbox/)

Can anyone share a real-word example where one will be better than other OR one some real world examples which is more natural with one or the other.

Edit: I request to reopen the question, as 1) question itself is very clear from the title. 2) There are articles on web (I noted a couple of them) that aim to clarify the question, but don't 3) The questions marked as duplicate of, are very different from what I asked.

Comment: There is no such thing as one being better than the other for smaller or bigger layout. They both are good to do what they were designed to do, no more, no less. Also, a question like this is off-topic and primarily opinion-based, so I also voted to close. I suggest you either become more specific or keep on searching/reading until you find an article that match what you look for, and with that getting an answer to your question

Comment: Here is a good article, which might, based on facts, give you a better picture about there differences: https://css-tricks.com/css-grid-replace-flexbox/

Comment: The link shared by you is good, however I also request to reopen the question, as 1) its very clear from the title. 2) There are articles on web (I noted a couple of them) that aim to clarify the question 3) The questions marked as duplicate of, are very different from what I asked.

Comment: I agree it may be somewhat opinion based, but I also found a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44051482/problems-building-a-flexbox-grid where your comment is: "...The CSS Grid is better, as you get a more responsive solution..." :)

Comment: The main reason your question were closed is being off-topic, by being opinion-based. The post you now links to, is more specific, hence it got an answer. What you can do is to break down your question into 2 new, where each being more specific for a certain use case. That might give you a better change. Also provide a code sample will greatly improve proper answers.

Comment: I wish I had the ability to answer this question as I can provide examples to back up what I say.
It all depends upon what you are building, preference, and ability to grasp the underlying principles.

Take a look at the complex layouts examples from this Guide: https://morganfeeney.com/guides/css-grid-vs-flexbox#complex-layouts

Note the differences in markup, amount of CSS etc.

Comment: "It all depends upon what you are building.... " Examples of  that is what I was looking for. some examples that show flexbox would be better or grid would be better.