# Is it possible to build the following layout with flex without nesting?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image]

Example:

Is it possible to built this kind of layout with flex without nesting? Purely, with a structure like this:

```
<div class="long">
</div>

<div class="short">
</div>

<div class="short">
</div>

<div class="short">
</div>

<div class="short">
</div>
```

Comment: If you want the boxes to dynamically adjust to content, and without script, then no.

Comment: With flexbox, yes it is possible if you can set a fixed height on the container. https://stackoverflow.com/q/34480760/3597276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. See below

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 320px;
}

.long {
  background-color: red;
  border: thin solid darkgray;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}

.short {
  background-color: blue;
  border: thin solid darkgray;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="long"></div>
  <div class="short"></div>
  <div class="short"></div>
  <div class="short"></div>
  <div class="short"></div>
</div>
```

*

Comment: Thanks! One question: why is there a huge space between the colored divs?

Comment: It's because by default the container div has a width 0f 100%. I have now defined the max-width in the code to reduce the space between the divs.