# Flexbox row, wrap items and take up vertical space

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm having a flexbox layout like this:

[image]

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Now, when the items get wrapped, the blue item will shift onto a new row:

[image]

As you can see there is some unwanted whitespace. Now what I want, but can't seem to achieve, is that the blue column takes up all available space:

[image]

Comment: that's not possible with flexbox (also not with floats, only with JS like masonry)

Comment: I have already answered a question with a similar case. that's impossible using flexbox. But you can achieve it with workarounds : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44706537/how-to-remove-this-space-between-blocks/44710027#44710027