# Flexbox to act like float

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a grid system that uses flexbox. At present I'm trying to work out if I can make it work with the following scenario.

```
<div class="flex-outer">
    <div class="flex-inner span-all red-box">
        <h2>Title</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-inner span-1of2 green-box">
        <div>Some text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-inner span-1of2 blue-box">
        <p>A table perhaps</p>
    </div>
</div>

.flex-outer {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.span-all {
    width:100%;
}
.span-1of2 {
    width:50%;
}
.red-box {
    background-color:Red;
}
.green-box {
    background-color:Green;
}
.blue-box {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

The html above could be used to create the following layout:

[image]

However on a certain breakpoint, I'd be looking to change the layout to something like this:

[image]

I can change the order of the green and blue boxes to suit, but on wrapping, the second box is position below the blue box. **This is the behaviour I expected**.

[image]

So, are there any flexbox tricks I can use to tuck the green box immediate beneath the red one?

Comment: Change `flex-direction` to `column`, maybe?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - this would surely result in a 1-column wide structure. I'm looking to preserve 2 columns.

Comment: I don't consider this question a duplicate as the previous question was not fully answered - a workaround was provided that involved pure floats - that's not what I'm looking for. Other's here may have a better answer.

Comment: Here is the dupe links solution applied to your code: https://jsfiddle.net/jt7e75oc/

Comment: And here with fixed height's and Flexbox column, and no `float`: https://jsfiddle.net/jt7e75oc/1/

Comment: Besides these 2 (you could use absolute position on the blue box, though consider `float` better), there is no Flexbox CSS way to accomplish what you ask.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34480760/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B Thanks...added it as a dupe link

Comment: @JohnOhara The linked answers does not have _pure float_, the first combine Flexbox with float, to achieve what you asked, the other link + my 2nd fiddle demo, use other _tricks_ to make accomplish your layout, as Flexbox can't alone (unless fixed height is used with Flexbox column, which my 2nd sample use)