# Adaptive multi-column layout without extra gaps between rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I'm struggling with a something that I called mosaic, because in my opinion is not a pure adaptive grid, but I'm not UX/UI master.

The best way to explain desired result is a [blueprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJEll.png), but what I have achieved is a [regular grid layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WUri.png) which doesn't fit my needs.

In few words I tried to implement with flexbox concept(display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap;).

I do not think that I need to share my code, because I have chosen inappropriate  method. Please, give me the basic idea. By this point, I have come to the conclusion that this can only be achieved with javascript.

Comment: Paulie_D, I’m not asking for a code, I’m looking for an idea. I’m stack with flexbox and now guess that is wrong technique for my case. That is why I have not posted my code — there is no sense. During research/google I couldn’t find any close implementation. Finally, if flexbox is what I really need I will be happy to post my minimized solution or at least a nutshell.

Comment: We don't give **ideas**...we solve *actual programming problems*. All you have done is dump a problem on us a question. That qualifies this as too broad and is thus **off-topic**. If you don't provide your code you **are** asking for code.

Answer (score 1):

The layout design you are after resembles [pinterest](https://www.pinterest.com/) layout and it is quite frustrated to implement that layout design using flexbox. You may consult this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480760/is-it-possible-for-flex-items-to-align-tightly-to-the-items-above-them), it asked the same question as you do and several solutions/tips/tricks were provided. My recommended solution is to use the [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/) which of course involves JavaScript.