# Is it possible with flexbox wrapping to break flow with the last few elements?

Tags: css, flexbox

2 questions. It seems that flexbox is a great tool for symmetrical layouts. However, when wrapping elements I cannot find examples of manipulating the last item(s) to kind of "break row flow" and either stick it to the right similar to how `justify-content:flex-end;` works or stack on top of each other.

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/BRacicot/pen/ZjrZQw)
and code:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.full-width {
  flex: 100%;
}

.fifty {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

.one-third {
  flex: 0 0 33%;
  /*how do we get the second .one-third to stick to the right?*/
}
```

```html
<div class="full-width">full-width</div>
<div class="fifty">fifty</div>
<div class="fifty">fifty</div>
<div class="one-third">one-third</div>
<div class="one-third">one-third <br/> How do we get this to stick to the right when part of a row?</div>
```

Here is a screenshot of what row wrapping looks like:
[image]

Here is what I'm after:
[image]

A similar question I can't find anything on is if it's possible to stack the last two elements in a row on top of each other.

Comment: It might help if you include a screenshot of the result you desire. You could do this in MS Paint or similar with a few rectangles. I for one I don't quite understand what you're trying to do just by the description you provided.

Comment: @ThisClark I included a codepen but have added a screenshot. Also this is not a duplicate. The question referenced has nothing to do with breaking out of the row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try doing this.

set the `margin-left` of the `.one-third` last element.

Please see the codepen link:
https://codepen.io/davecar21/pen/QBQRvL

```html
body{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.full-width{
  flex:100%;
}
.fifty{
  flex:0 0 50%;
}
.one-third{
  flex:0 0 33%;
  // how do we get the second .one-third to stick to the right?
}

.one-third:last-child{
  margin-left: auto;
  // will make the last-child margin-left to be auto so it will align to the right side
}




<div class="full-width">full-width</div>
<div class="fifty">fifty</div>
<div class="fifty">fifty</div>
<div class="one-third">one-third</div>
<div class="one-third">one-third <br/> How do we get this to stick to the right when part of a row?</div>
```

---

> A similar question I can't find anything on is if it's possible to
>   stack the last two elements in a row on top of each other.

I think it can only be possible if the two stack elements will have a width is greater than 50%.

```
div.one-third:nth-child(4),
div.one-third:nth-child(5){
      margin:auto;
      flex:0 0 55%;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I recently read about this too! Do'h! Any advice on the second part of my question, stacking the last two elements?

Comment: @BenRacicot Please see my updated answer about the second part of your question.

Comment: could I ask you to revisit the stacking row items on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51937861/flexbox-when-wrapping-in-a-row-how-can-i-stack-two-elements-without-extra-mark ? Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480760/is-it-possible-for-flex-items-to-align-tightly-to-the-items-above-them @Michael_B recommends `flex-flow: column wrap` but I can't get examples to work yet. This could be huge!

Comment: @BenRacicot I think `flex-flow: column wrap` is not a option as he said in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377343/css-only-masonry-layout-but-with-elements-ordered-horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377343/css-only-masonry-layout-but-with-elements-ordered-horizontally). it will be best to used grid.