# Make height of div equal to the height of the content in flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I make the height of the child div be only as long as the content (text in this case) is ?

```css
.wrapp{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 1200px;
}

.child{
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 20px
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapp'>
<div class='child'>text text text texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext text</div>
<div class='child'>text texttext text</div>


</div>
```

Comment: Add `align-items: flex-start` to the container.

Comment: Don't use display flex, just use display inline-block or display block with float right/left.

Comment: @Michael_B That works, but if i have 4 divs, 2 and the other 2 underneath them, there is space between them. Is there a way I can get rid of that too ?

Comment: Sounds like a Masonry layout. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34480760/3597276). If that isn't relevant, you can post another question.