# Column Count 3 never leaves a row with 1 item

Tags: css, flexbox, multiple-columns, column-count

I've noticed that when I use column-count: 3 in my code and I have 7 items for example. The first two columns will have 3 elements each and the third column will have only one element (see picture for example).

Is this the normal behavior of column-count, or should column-count be filling all column equally?

[image]

UPDATED-

I tried messing around with caiovisk answer and I changed the code from li elements to divs since that is what I am working with.

That seems to work great but in my situation sometimes elements might be bigger than others causing gaps (see the picture below). How do you fix this issue using the flex method?

```css
.columns-3 {
  flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 20px);
  margin: 10px;
 }
 .redBox {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
 }
 .bigger {
  height: 150px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div class="columns-3 redBox bigger"></div>
  <div class="columns-3 redBox"></div>
  <div class="columns-3 redBox"></div>
  <div class="columns-3 redBox bigger"></div>
  <div class="columns-3 redBox"></div>
  <div class="columns-3 redBox"></div>
  <div class="columns-3 redBox"></div>
  <div class="columns-3 redBox"></div>
  <div class="columns-3 redBox bigger"></div>
  <div class="columns-3 redBox"></div>
  <div class="columns-3 redBox"></div>
  <div class="columns-3 redBox"></div>
  <div class="columns-3 redBox"></div>
 </div>
```

[image: Flex Picture]

Comment: Check if you got `position:relative;` on the (I assume) li element. Remove it, if you have it.

Comment: Where is your code?? pl;ease read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34480760/3597276

Answer (score 0):

Check if you got `position:relative;` on the (I assume) li element.

Comment: I do have relative positioning. What positioning should it be?

Comment: Remove it. Make an element inside the li, "holding" the element that require position: relative;

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is normal behaviour. It will separate the elements or content by the specified value on `column-count` then display it in `columns`. If you are using `ul`, `ol`, `div` or any elements that is not a `text` it will place them vertically, which may not be the desired result, but for `text` it make absolutely sense.
see docs: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-multicol-1/#cc

If you would like to divide your inner elements into columns and divide it horizontally, you can use the `flexbox`, see approach  below:

```css
.columns{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.columns-2 li {
    flex-basis: 50%;
}
.columns-3 li {
    flex-basis: 33.3334%;
}
.columns-4 li {
    flex-basis: 25%;
}
```

```html
<h1>2 Columns</h1>
<ul class="columns columns-2">
<li>Column 1</li>
<li>Column 2</li>
<li>Column 3</li>
<li>Column 4</li>
<li>Column 5</li>
<li>Column 6</li>
<li>Column 7</li>
</ul>
<h1>3 Columns</h1>
<ul class="columns columns-3">
<li>Column 1</li>
<li>Column 2</li>
<li>Column 3</li>
<li>Column 4</li>
<li>Column 5</li>
<li>Column 6</li>
<li>Column 7</li>
</ul>
<h1>4 Columns</h1>
<ul class="columns columns-4">
<li>Column 1</li>
<li>Column 2</li>
<li>Column 3</li>
<li>Column 4</li>
<li>Column 5</li>
<li>Column 6</li>
<li>Column 7</li>
</ul>
```

**EDITED:**

As per the answer edit, you have set `height: 50px;` to your `.redbox` and it is limiting the element to fill the height. Set it to `min-height: 50px;`

```
.redBox {
        min-height: 50px;
        ...
}
```

```css
.columns {
  display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap;
}
.columns.columns-3 > div {
    flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 20px);
    margin: 10px;
}
.columns.redBox > div {
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
.bigger {
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns columns-3 redBox">
  <div class="bigger"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="bigger"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="bigger"></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello caiovisk! Thank you for the answer. I had a follow up question and updated my original question. Thank you!