# Flexbox wrapping elements outside div

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to wrap elements in a column direction. My first element is 100% wide and all other elements are 50% wide. When it comes time to wrap, the last few elements wrap beginning from the first element that is 100% wide instead of going down to the second line.

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/e4j16apg/

This is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.ca {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.ca-1 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="ca ca-1">ca-1</div>
  <div class="ca ca-2">ca-2</div>
  <div class="ca ca-3">ca-3</div>
  <div class="ca ca-3">ca-3</div>
  <div class="ca ca-4">ca-4</div>
  <div class="ca ca-5">ca-5</div>
  <div class="ca ca-6">ca-6</div>
  <div class="ca ca-7">ca-7</div>
  <div class="ca ca-8">ca-8</div>
  <div class="ca ca-9">ca-9</div>
  <div class="ca ca-10">ca-10</div>
</div>
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't achieve what you want with flexbox, but you can using `columns` (and making the first element span all columns):

```css
.container {
  columns: 2;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  column-gap: 0;
  /* height: 200px; */
}

.ca {
  border: 1px solid red;
  break-inside: avoid;
  /* height: calc(100% / 6); */
}

.ca-1 {
  column-span: all;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="ca ca-1">ca-1</div>
  <div class="ca ca-2">ca-2</div>
  <div class="ca ca-3">ca-3</div>
  <div class="ca ca-3">ca-3</div>
  <div class="ca ca-4">ca-4</div>
  <div class="ca ca-5">ca-5</div>
  <div class="ca ca-6">ca-6</div>
  <div class="ca ca-7">ca-7</div>
  <div class="ca ca-8">ca-8</div>
  <div class="ca ca-9">ca-9</div>
  <div class="ca ca-10">ca-10</div>
</div>
```

Also note that, by default, `columns` calculates the total height of all children that wrap and wraps as close as possible to half (when there're two). So you don't actually need a fixed height for it. And you don't need the `height` set on children, especially if they have uneven heights.

CSS `columns` are designed to layout as newspaper columns out of the box, which seems to be what you're after.

To prevent breaks inside children, use `break-inside: avoid;`.

Comment: The problem is that the OP wants 2-6 in the first column and then 7-10 in the second. I don't think this can be achieved using `flex-box` without adding additional markup (e.g. wrapping or grouping divs)

Comment: @disinfor, you're right. I edited my answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

*You wrote:*

> When it comes time to wrap, the last few elements wrap beginning from the first element that is 100% wide instead of going down to the second line.

That's the problem. You believe there is a "second line". There isn't.

Once you make your first element take 100% width, you've defined the width of the column.

By making the subsequent elements 50% width, you're telling them to consume 50% of that column.

The elements that wrap create a second column.

They can't wrap under the 100% element and next to the first set of 50% elements because *you can't make elements wrap onto the same line*.

So you don't have to change your HTML, use CSS Grid for the layout:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(9, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.ca {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.ca-1 {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="ca ca-1">ca-1</div>
  <div class="ca ca-2">ca-2</div>
  <div class="ca ca-3">ca-3</div>
  <div class="ca ca-3">ca-3</div>
  <div class="ca ca-4">ca-4</div>
  <div class="ca ca-5">ca-5</div>
  <div class="ca ca-6">ca-6</div>
  <div class="ca ca-7">ca-7</div>
  <div class="ca ca-8">ca-8</div>
  <div class="ca ca-9">ca-9</div>
  <div class="ca ca-10">ca-10</div>
</div>
```

More details here:

- [Is it possible for flex items to align tightly to the items above them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34480760/3597276)