# Is there a way to increase the height of a div when using flex?

Tags: css, flexbox, grid-layout

I have a grid layout of 8 divs.  I am trying to increase the height of the 5th div and decrease the height of the 8th div.  Every way I have tried I get a big gap.  I haven't used masonry isotope before and need to reorder the divs for mobile so thought to use flexbox.  I would really appreciate some help and pointing to some good tutorials when needing to use different heights in a grid layout.  Is flexbox the best way to do this

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: baseline;
  align-content: start;
  width: 1058px;
}

.item {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/635x300.png">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/267x300.png">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/267x300.png">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/267x300.png">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/267x300.png">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/267x300.png">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/267x300.png">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/267x300.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

?

Comment: A flex solution may be hacky, this is a really good case for using CSS Grid.

Comment: Thanks I did come across CSS Grid but wasn't sure if I could re-order the divs in mobile?

Comment: You sure can. Just set the `grid-area` for elements differently in your media queries.

Comment: Perfect thank you so much.  Someone has seen my question and closed it as it is more or less the same thing I was asking.  For anyone else a good explanation not to use Flexbox for this kind of thing: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480760/is-it-possible-for-flex-items-to-align-tightly-to-the-items-above-them