# How can I have flex elements shrink to their contents with react-native and align?

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox, react-flexbox-grid

I have:

```
        <StyledSurface style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
            {conversations.map((c, i) => (
                <Surface style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', width: '46%', margin: '2%', flexDirection: 'column', flexShrink: 1, alignSelf: 'flex-start'}} key={i}>
                    <Text style={{flex: 1}}>{c.title}</Text>
                </Surface>
            ))}
        </StyledSurface>
```

and this ends up looking like:

[image]

But I want each red box to shrink (vertically) to fit the contents and have equal spacing?

What am I missing?

Comment: I think you want `alignContent: 'flex-start'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34480760/3597276

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the View container add this:

```
alignSelf: 'flex-start',
```

Should do the trick

Comment: Closer - but I updated the question to reflect my update