# Flexbox Grid Centered Coloumn + 2 Objects per Row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'd like to build a Grid with Flexbox that contains 2 Objects per row. These Objects should be centered along a vertical coloumn and have different widths (as on the picture). Does anyone have an Idea how to approach it?

[image]

I'd like to use flexbox to be able to swith on to 1 Object per row and keep the correct order. Otherwise I would have nested divs and alligned the objects with

```
left:0;
```

or

```
right:0;
```

but then I wouldn't be able to keep the order on mobile. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Flexbox can't do that. In fact, other than actual *positioning* I'm not aware of **any** layout method that *can*.

Comment: @Paulie_D do you have an idea how I could apporach it otherwise?

Comment: Basically, you need JS - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470070/how-to-create-grid-tile-view-with-css

Comment: @Paulie_D thanks! I'll take a look into that

Comment: In an afterthought, although it won't help you *yet* CSS Grids might be something for the future but they're not here yet.

Comment: I think it really needs JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to get this working I used masonry.js
I built a grid with 2 grid_items per row at 50% width.
Then I inserted the Boxes into the grid_items and gave them float:right / float:left.

Css:

```
.grid {
width: 100vw;
}

.grid-item { 
width: 50%; 
margin-bottom: 30px;
background-color:grey;
}
```