# How to make flexbox grid images responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I am trying to create a flexbox grid with images that have different widths and heights which i want to behave responsive when shown on different screen sizes. I have the grid now, but i do not know how to make it responsive. I have tried to apply responsive classes within bootstrap to the current layout but without any luck. I have also tried masonry, but it did not solve my problem.

So the question is, how do i make this responsive and is it even the right approach?

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex_container">
  <div class="flex_group__1">
    <img src="holder.js/460x670" />
    <img src="holder.js/460x408" />
  </div>
  <div class="flex_group__2">
    <img src="holder.js/645x813">
    <img src="holder.js/645x265">
  </div>
  <div class="flex_group__3">
    <img src="holder.js/808x330"/>
    <div class="flex_group__3_inner_bottom">
      <img src="holder.js/452x748"/>
      <img src="holder.js/356x748"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flex_group__1, .flex_group__2, .flex_group__3, .flex_group__3_inner_bottom, .flex_container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex_container {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex_group__3 {
  flex-direction: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.flex_group__1, .flex_group__2, .flex_group__3 {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex_container * {
  border: 1px solid;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I found another sample of mine, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465475/challenging-layout-how-to-achieve

Comment: And this will work for my odd sized images?

Comment: Yes, ... and I decided to make a first code base :), to help you getting started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version with a layout closer to the one you asked for, and easier to follow.

With this you either set `background-image` (as I did in below stack snippet) on each image holder, or add an `img` element to the markup.

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/htjccmfg/)

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper:after {
  padding-top: 56.25%;   /* 16:9 ratio */
  display: block;
  content: ' ';
}
.flex-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
}
.flex-container > div {           /*  .flex-col-1, .flex-col-2, .flex-col-3  */
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flex-container > div > div {     /*  .flex-row-1, .flex-row-2    */
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
}

.flex-col-1 {
  width: 25%;
}
  .flex-col-1 .flex-row-1 {
    height: 70%;
    background: #ddd url(https://placeimg.com/400/600/arch) no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .flex-col-1 .flex-row-2 {
    height: 30%;
    background: #ddd url(https://placeimg.com/400/600/arch) no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
  }

.flex-col-2 {
  width: 32.5%;
}
  .flex-col-2 .flex-row-1 {
    height: 80%;
    background: #ddd url(https://placeimg.com/400/600/arch) no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .flex-col-2 .flex-row-2 {
    height: 20%;
    background: #ddd url(https://placeimg.com/400/600/arch) no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
  }

.flex-col-3 {
  width: 42.5%;
}
  .flex-col-3 .flex-row-1 {
    height: 44%;
    background: #ddd url(https://placeimg.com/400/600/arch) no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .flex-col-3 .flex-row-2 {
    height: 56%;
  }

.flex-col-3-inner {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}
  .flex-col-3-inner .flex-col-1-inner {
    width: 40%;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background: #ddd url(https://placeimg.com/400/600/arch) no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .flex-col-3-inner .flex-col-2-inner {
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: 5px;
    background: #ddd url(https://placeimg.com/400/600/arch) no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-col-1">
      <div class="flex-row-1">
      </div>
      <div class="flex-row-2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-col-2">
      <div class="flex-row-1">
      </div>
      <div class="flex-row-2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-col-3">
      <div class="flex-row-1">
      </div>
      <div class="flex-row-2">
        <div class="flex-col-3-inner">
          <div class="flex-col-1-inner">
          </div>
          <div class="flex-col-2-inner">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

2:nd sample, using `img`, where I also added this rule

```
.flex-container img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

and as you can see, with a layout like this, `img` elements need more individual touch to make them behave.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper:after {
  padding-top: 56.25%;   /* 16:9 ratio */
  display: block;
  content: ' ';
}
.flex-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
}
.flex-container > div {           /*  .flex-col-1, .flex-col-2, .flex-col-3  */
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flex-container > div > div {     /*  .flex-row-1, .flex-row-2    */
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
}

.flex-container img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-col-1 {
  width: 25%;
}
  .flex-col-1 .flex-row-1 {
    height: 70%;
    background: #ddd;
  }
  .flex-col-1 .flex-row-2 {
    height: 30%;
    background: #ddd;
  }

.flex-col-2 {
  width: 32.5%;
}
  .flex-col-2 .flex-row-1 {
    height: 80%;
    background: #ddd;
  }
  .flex-col-2 .flex-row-2 {
    height: 20%;
    background: #ddd;
  }

.flex-col-3 {
  width: 42.5%;
}
  .flex-col-3 .flex-row-1 {
    height: 44%;
    background: #ddd;
  }
  .flex-col-3 .flex-row-2 {
    height: 56%;
  }

.flex-col-3-inner {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}
  .flex-col-3-inner .flex-col-1-inner {
    width: 40%;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background: #ddd;
  }
  .flex-col-3-inner .flex-col-2-inner {
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: 5px;
    background: #ddd;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-col-1">
      <div class="flex-row-1">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/600/arch" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="flex-row-2">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/600/arch" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-col-2">
      <div class="flex-row-1">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/600/arch" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="flex-row-2">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/600/arch" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-col-3">
      <div class="flex-row-1">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/600/arch" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="flex-row-2">
        <div class="flex-col-3-inner">
          <div class="flex-col-1-inner">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/600/arch" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="flex-col-2-inner">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/600/arch" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here are 2 more variants, one using `background-size: contain;`

- https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/htjccmfg/1

and the other `background-size: 100% 100%`

- https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/htjccmfg/2

Comment: Very awesome example! It made me realise that i should design it much more simpler next time ;-) Apart from that, when i add the images as <img> to the flex boxes, some of them are stretched, which they shouldn't be. Is that the behavior as expected?

Comment: @JavaCake Thanks, and it is, unless you set them up one-by-one. I updated and added a 2:nd sample + an extra CSS rule, play with that and you'll see what happens. Probably you'll need to set individual values on each image, so using `background-image` has some benefits though, especially as you have such predefined layout.

Comment: I see what you mean, because i stumbled into the same problem as there is with this example. The two images on the lower corner are a bit "out of control"..

Comment: @JavaCake Yepp, and as each image needs to fit within a certain aspect ratio, you have to set that up, or else they will distort. The `background-size: cover` does that automatically and cut the image either at height or width, so when using `img` one need to set that up for each image.

Comment: So i need to calculate the pixels to percent for each flex cell in order for this to function properly?

Comment: @JavaCake I will see how I can make a sample to show what I mean, meanwhile, may I ask why you want `img` in favor of `background-image`?

Comment: Because i would like to see the entire image rather than a part of it, which is basically the downside for using roughly estimated widths.

Comment: @JavaCake Okay, what should happen when the image's height/width doesn't fit inside the flex holder, like being to wide or to high? ... Should the background shine through?

Comment: @JavaCake Check this demo, all images fully visible, though when they don't have same aspect ratio, background color will cover the rest of the flex holders area: https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/htjccmfg/1/

Comment: @JavaCake And this version squeeze them to fit: https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/htjccmfg/2/

Comment: I am considering a very cumbersome solution based on your example where i benefit from calc and possibly JS calculating the width and height in percentage. I have just made a simple example which works.

Comment: Those are two very interesting examples, but i cannot avoid setting some crazy width and height sizes which reflect the real values of the images for now, but i am considering JS to set the values accordingly just to avoid sitting with a calculator and finding the real percent value of the image. I have to say that the basis is really good.

Comment: @JavaCake No matter which solution, either the flex holder need to adjust or the image, and the image can either be cut or distort or leave unused space at side or top/bottom.

Comment: I can use this example, and simply adjust the width and height of the boxes. That would get me to the goal quite fast, and perhaps rather static, but it does not really matter at this stage.

Comment: @JavaCake I just hope what I tried to make use see is, that it is quite easy to do when you wrap your head around it a little.

Comment: I was hoping for a much smarter solution, but this would of course be an attempt to search for the golden unicorn. Initially i thought that the isotope/masonry library would be able to do all these "silly" calculations for me as a part of the framework, but it does not really do as i want it to. As long as i do not change the structure and measure the elements sizes by using JS i should have a somewhat flexible grid.