# Bootstrap Grid System fill all space

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like the grid to fill all the space eg

[image]

and not

[image]

My example has a fixed number of Panels, my project does not..

```html
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">

  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading sas-heading-green" xng-class="{1:'sas-heading-green',2:'sas-heading-orange',0:'sas-heading-red'}[innercount % 3]">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Content
        <button class="btn btn-default">
          Hello
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading sas-heading-green" xng-class="{1:'sas-heading-green',2:'sas-heading-orange',0:'sas-heading-red'}[innercount % 3]">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Content
        <button class="btn btn-default">
          Hello
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading sas-heading-green" xng-class="{1:'sas-heading-green',2:'sas-heading-orange',0:'sas-heading-red'}[innercount % 3]">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading sas-heading-green" xng-class="{1:'sas-heading-green',2:'sas-heading-orange',0:'sas-heading-red'}[innercount % 3]">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
           <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
        </ul>
        <button class="btn btn-default">
          Hello
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading sas-heading-green" xng-class="{1:'sas-heading-green',2:'sas-heading-orange',0:'sas-heading-red'}[innercount % 3]">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Content
        <button class="btn btn-default">
          Hello
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading sas-heading-green" xng-class="{1:'sas-heading-green',2:'sas-heading-orange',0:'sas-heading-red'}[innercount % 3]">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Content
        <button class="btn btn-default">
          Hello
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading sas-heading-green" xng-class="{1:'sas-heading-green',2:'sas-heading-orange',0:'sas-heading-red'}[innercount % 3]">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Content
        <button class="btn btn-default">
          Hello
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap can't do that unless you build the columns manually. Floats don't work that way. Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470070/how-to-create-grid-tile-view-with-css

Comment: happy to remove it, I just dident know to search for the term Masonry , my google foo was weak :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this natively with Bootstrap, as floats do not align in this way. However, there are plugins that will allow you to do alignment in this sort of way. One really good one is [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

[Here is a Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4bm8t82q/) of Masonry

It's very simple to use in its basic form:

```
<div class="container" data-masonry='{ "itemSelector":".col-sm-4", "fitWidth": true }'>
```

Comment: that's perfect, but now I have tried it I have gone with a new ROW every 3 cols which due to the content just looks better