# Using nth-child to display divs side by side-one larger div on the left two smaller on the right-but the second smaller div keeps getting pushed down

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm playing around with nth-child and trying to create a layout that looks like this

[image]

but for some reason the larger divs will only allow one smaller div to display to its side, it pushes the second smaller div down like this:

[image]

even though according to the dimensions they should fit. What am I missing or not understanding here? I've included my HTML and CSS below:

```css
#main {
  text-align: center;
}
.boxes {
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 45%;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.boxes:nth-child(6n-2) {
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 420px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.boxes:nth-child(6n-5) {
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 420px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="boxes">box1</div>
  <div class="boxes">box2</div>
  <div class="boxes">box3</div>
  <div class="boxes">box4</div>
  <div class="boxes">box5</div>
  <div class="boxes">box6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is called a **Masonry** layout. Sure you can try floating different children or wrap each group in a container but this requires a lot of maintenance and is not flexible.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470070/how-to-create-grid-tile-view-with-css

Answer (score 0):

you need to assign float-parameters to these boxes: `float:left` to box 1,2,3 , `float:right` to box 4,5,6

Here's a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPojBJ

(widths / margins still need to be tweaked)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you, see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/c259LrpL/44/

change `.boxes{display: inline-block}` to `.boxes{float: left}`

```
.boxes {
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 45%;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

Then float the other big box right

```
.boxes:nth-child(4) {
    float: right;
    margin-right: calc(100% - (90% + 30px)) !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well. Although I'd still be interested in knowing why my original solution doesn't work if you have any ideas, as it seems like it should.

Comment: @nickstobie Its because you were using `inline-block` incorrectly, see here for a good explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189810/css-display-inline-vs-inline-block

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
.main{
    height:500px;
    width:400px;
}
div.subDiv{
    height:50%;
    margin:5px;
}
div.subDiv>div{
    width:47%;
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}
div.subDiv>div>div{
    height: 122.5px;
    background-color:gray;
}
div.subDiv>div>div+div{
    margin-top:5px
}
.gray{
    background-color:gray;
}
</style>

<div class="main">
    <div class="subDiv">
        <div class="gray"></div>
        <div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subDiv">
        <div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="gray"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hi. It will be more easy if you will do the above implementations. As you can see, I didn't use float:left because it is more efficient to use display:inline-block;