# Eliminating dead space in masonry-like float layout

Tags: html, css

I am working on a product page layout that has two columns with various height items. I am trying to avoid nesting the items in two column containers, so that I can have optimal order of elements on small screens that go to one column.

The problem I am running into is that sometimes the second block (floated left) is longer than the first block (floated right), and sometimes the opposite is true. The problem occurs when the third block is given `clear: left` to make sure it's as far right as it can go, the fourth block will not go above the top of the third block.

[image: floated layout with gap]

Here is a CodePen with the code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jAQdEK?editors=1100#anon-login

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470070/how-to-create-grid-tile-view-with-css

Comment: This is possible with flexbox but, in general, it requires a known height of the container.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do looks like a layout table to me. Using `display` types `table`, `table-row` and `table-cell` might be an easy and solid solution for that. See:

http://codepen.io/wortwart/pen/grQqzv

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for. I would like the blocks to only be as tall as the content in them, rather than share the height of the taller block next to them as in your example.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your requirements. Maybe flexbox is the right thing for your problem if you can afford to ignore IE <= 9.