# CSS inline-block clean folding

Tags: css

Is there a way to make my block-elements behave like in this example:

---

Desired effect:

```
|----|----|
|1111|2222|
|1111|----|
|1111|3333|
|----|----|
|4444|
|----|
```

Actual result:

```
|----|----|
|1111|2222|
|1111|----|
|1111|
|----|----|
|3333|4444|
|----|----|
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color:red;
  width:220px;
}

.block {
  background-color:blue;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  margin:4px;
}

.long {
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block long">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a masonry layout - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470070/how-to-create-grid-tile-view-with-css

Comment: What does "clean folding" mean here?

Comment: @Paulie_D Not exactly, I would like number 4 to occupy the space where 5 is in the example.

Comment: Yeah...CSS can't do that. That's why there's JS.

Comment: @BSMP I meant folding without leaving white-space except at the end of the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think best option for this is to  use [`masonry`](http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html) plugin.

```js
$('.wrapper').masonry({
  columnWidth: 1,
  itemSelector: '.block'
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color:red;
  width:220px;
}

.block {
  background-color:blue;
  height:100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin:4px;
}

.long {
  height:180px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4.1.1/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block long"></div><div class="block"></div><div class="block"></div><div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <div class="block long">

    </div>
    <div class="block">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="block">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this will have the desired effect with the same css

Comment: This changes nothing I'm afraid.

Comment: load up the plunker and run it. you will see the elements align correctly

https://plnkr.co/edit/S5OTUrAM5ESrF7sgGdQ2?p=info

Answer (score 0):

You can add to the `.wrapper` class,

```
column-count: 2;
column-gap: 0px;
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color:red;
  width:220px;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 0px;
}

.block {
  background-color:blue;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  margin:4px;
}

.long {
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block long">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works brilliant in the example, but unfortunately it blew up my entire layout in the actual project. I'm on debugging tour now ;)

Comment: This will not order the divs as required.

Answer (score 0):

use `float:left` to block properties

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color:red;
 display: inline-block;
width: 220px;
}

.block {
  background-color:blue;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
float: left;
  
vertical-align:top;
  margin:4px;
}

.long {
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block long">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works for my example, but then if you have more elements there will be white-space on the left instead of on the right ;)