# Make flexbox fill up all space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have boxes in which I'm using flexbox for their layout. Flexbox makes the rows 'organized'. Meaning, if 1 box's height is larger than all the others, all the boxes on the second row get pushed down, and there is space under the boxes first row that have a smaller height.

Here's an image of what I mean:

[image]

There's space under box #01 because box #2 has a larger height. I want box #4 to go right under box #1.

How can I make a all boxes to fill up space right above them?

#### JSFiddle

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 400px;
}
.tile {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}
#n2 {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="tile" id="n1">01</div>
  <div class="tile" id="n2">02</div>
  <div class="tile" id="n3">03</div>
  <div class="tile" id="n4">04</div>
  <div class="tile" id="n5">05</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to do something like this, I would suggest http://masonry.desandro.com/ which is a javascript grid layout library. It works by placing elements in optimal position based on available vertical space, sort of like a mason fitting stones in a wall.

Comment: A misconception people have about `flexbox` is that it is a two dimensional layout. You can have column **or** row direction within a `flex-container`, not both at the same time. There is no possible way you can do this without having 2 or more `flex-containers` or setting a fixed `height`.

Comment: @Ricky_Ruiz [it is possible to do this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35097136/1529630) with forced line breaks. It's just that for some reason only Firefox cared to implement them

Comment: @Oriol I didn't know about this. Quite interesting, thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `flex-direction: column` along with `flex-wrap: wrap`, but you won't be able to preserve the order of the elements.

A JavaScript library like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) might be worth looking into.

Comment: If I do `flex-direction: column`, I will have to specify a height (for it to have multiple columns), which can't...

Comment: All the more you should use Masonry.

Answer (score 0):

Like Darryl says, you want to do this with `flex-flow: column wrap;` and a fixed height on the parent element. [This page](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) on CSS-Tricks is invaluable to understanding the syntax, but basically changing the flex-direction flips it sideways. You can specify the order of children by setting the `order: XX` on the child tiles.

Comment: If I do `flex-direction: column`, I will have to specify a height (for it to have multiple columns), which can't...

Comment: You can't specify an explicit height for the parent container? You might be able to fudge it with a `min-height` or `max-height`, especially with the `vh` unit, which bases off your viewport height. If not possible, then yeah, Masonry's your best bet.