# What am I doing wrong here ? html and css

Tags: html, css

Okay here is the desired result:

[image]

Here is the result I got:

[image]

The bottom row is in a straight line and not going in between the other containers like it need it be to be. I don't know how to go about getting the results I want like in the screenshot #1.

I hope someone can help me out. Thanks in advance.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding-top: 7px;
}

.container {
    width: 948px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.container ul {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.container ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: auto; 
    padding: 10px;
    margin-right: 24px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.container ul li:nth-child(3n) {
    margin: 0;
}

.container ul li span {
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.container ul li p {
    color: #333;
    text-align: justify;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.thumbnail-con {
    width: 100%;
    height: 174px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SimpleRead</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="styles/main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="thumbnail-con"></div>
                <br>
                <span>Business</span>
                <h2>Caterpillar to close Illinois plant, lay off 800 workers</h2>
                <br>
                
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="thumbnail-con"></div>
                <br>
                <span>Celebrity</span>
                <h2>Nicki Minaj signs with modeling agency</h2>
                <br>
                <p>Prosecutors charged a white Baltimore racist Monday with murder as an act of terrorism for traveling to New York City and allegedly killing a 66-year-old black man with a sword.</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="thumbnail-con"></div>
                <br>
                <span>US</span>
                <h2>Racist ‘assassin’ indicted as terrorist in NYC murder of black man</h2>
                <br>
                <p>Prosecutors charged a white Baltimore racist Monday with murder as an act of terrorism for traveling to New York City and allegedly killing a 66-year-old black man with a sword.</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="thumbnail-con"></div>
                <br>
                <span>US</span>
                <h2>Racist ‘assassin’ indicted as terrorist in NYC murder of black man</h2>
                <br>
                <p>Prosecutors charged a white Baltimore racist Monday with murder as an act of terrorism for traveling to New York City and allegedly killing a 66-year-old black man with a sword.</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="thumbnail-con"></div>
                <br>
                <span>US</span>
                <h2>Racist ‘assassin’ indicted as terrorist in NYC murder of black man</h2>
                <br>
                <p>Prosecutors charged a white Baltimore racist Monday with murder as an act of terrorism for traveling to New York City and allegedly killing a 66-year-old black man with a sword.</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="thumbnail-con"></div>
                <br>
                <span>US</span>
                <h2>Racist ‘assassin’ indicted as terrorist in NYC murder of black man</h2>
                <br>
                <p>Prosecutors charged a white Baltimore racist Monday with murder as an act of terrorism for traveling to New York City and allegedly killing a 66-year-old black man with a sword.</p>
            </li>
            
        </ul>
        
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No crystal balls available.. Try adding the relevant html/css/js

Comment: Right, I totally forgot lol

Comment: You could use columns but then they would go top/down and then left/right so 2nd would be below 1st etc.. Otherwise you need to use some javascript. [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) seems a good candidate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Create Grid/Tile View with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470070/how-to-create-grid-tile-view-with-css)

Comment: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 0):

That layout is called the **Masonry Grid**. It can be achieved using CSS grid columns but it is quite a muddled task, i would recommend that you use a jQuery plugin like [this one](https://masonry.desandro.com/).

Hope this helps :)