# Place each div on the "most left" possible preserving order

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to create a page where each `div` is to the "most left" possible, I don't know how to explain it, so I've created 3 example images

I could use a simple `float: left` but in that case in the second image the `div 4` would be placed at the right of `div 2`

Does anyone have any advice?
I can also use bootstrap if it can help me in this case

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

Comment: P.S.: the div quantity is dynamic

Comment: Learn flexbox - it will probably be easier to achieve this with flexbox than floats.

Comment: I don't think there is **any** layout method that can do this...not even CSS-Grid. My initial thought is that you will need Javascript.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470070/how-to-create-grid-tile-view

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your issue correctly the effect can be achieved with grid-area, I recently watched a tutorial by Morten Rand-Hendriksen which was really helpful

Comment: but grid-area is like setting each element with position: absolute and the elements will not be reorder during resizing, right?