# How to align div's with different heights?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I'm trying to align div's like here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoBPg.png

But the result is wrong: https://codepen.io/online123/pen/VwvGoQP

HTML:

```
  <div class="under d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center">
  <div class="box">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 2<br/><br/><br/>end</div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 3</div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 4</div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 5<br/><br/>end</div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 6</div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 7</div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 8</div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 9<br/><br/><br/><br/>end</div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 10</div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 11</div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 12</div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.under {
    width:70%;
    margin:auto;
    padding-top:40px;
    padding-bottom:40px;
    text-align:center;
    border: 1px solid green;
    overflow:auto; 
  justify-content:center;
    position:relative;
}

.box {
    text-align:center;
    width:314px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    align-self:flex-start;
}




body {
    height:100%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:center;
    background-color:#262626!important;
    color:#ddd!important;
    font-family: 'Jost', sans-serif;
}
```

How to do it? Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: Can I ask why you are using `<br>` ?

Comment: Only for showing the different heights.

Comment: Note: the `<br>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/q/8470070/6293856

Comment: Have tryied but it don't works. It stretch the **.box** width. Or stay with 3 columns when screen is small.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it in a static way not making any loop for map over them then you can acheive it in like this way.

```css
.under {
 width:70%;
 margin:auto;
 padding-top:40px;
 padding-bottom:40px;
 text-align:center;
 border: 1px solid green;
 overflow:auto; 
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items:flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
 position:relative;
 column-count: 5;
}

.box {
 text-align:center;
 width:314px;
  min-width:314px;
 padding:10px;
 margin:10px;
 display:inline-block;
 box-shadow: 0px 4px #1c1c1c;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
 background-color: #363636;
 border: 1px solid red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 2450px) {
  .under {
   column-count: 4;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1900px) {
  .under {
   column-count: 3;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1350px) {
  .under {
   column-count: 2;
      flex-direction:column;
      align-items:center;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .under {
   column-count: 1;
      flex-direction:column;
      align-items:center;
  }
}


asd{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column
}


body {
 height:100%;
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
 flex-direction:row;
 justify-content:center;
 background-color:#262626!important;
 color:#ddd!important;
 font-family: 'Jost', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="under">
  <div class='asd'>
    <div class="box">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="box">Flex item 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 2<br><br><br>end</div>
  <div class='asd'>
    <div class="box">Flex item 3</div>  
    <div class="box">Flex item 6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 5<br><br/>end</div>
  <div class='asd'>
    <div class="box">Flex item 7</div>
    <div class="box">Flex item 8</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">Flex item 9<br><br><br><br>end</div>
  <div class='asd'>
    <div class="box">Flex item 10</div>
    <div class="box">Flex item 11</div>
    <div class="box">Flex item 12</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE THE ANSWER PLEASE HAVE LOOK AND RUN**

Comment: @inside_tank yeah it will work but only you need to do is to add media query to adjust the width of **.box** to fit it to the mobile/smaller screen.

Comment: The width of  .box should be allways 314px. By smaller screen it should be less columns.

Comment: then in media query change the **`flex-direction`** from **`column`** to **`row`**

Comment: It's don't works like I want. When you make your browser smaller and smaller the **.box'es** should change thier positions. The **.under** should be allways **70%**.

Comment: As i said in the answer if you want it in static other otherwise you can create another type of this design and hide that on desktop and show on mobile using media query.

Comment: I don't want it in static order. It should be dynamic (depends on the browser size). Is there any option to do it?

Comment: Here is an example how sould it work: https://leh.tv/ Try to make your browser smaller and smaller and see what happens with the boxes.

Comment: Do you have an another solution?

Comment: I don't think if you want the sequence like in image it is not possible but if you want it like in a sequence of 1,2,3,4,5..... then it is possible to make it

Comment: Sequence on image is only example. The sequence doesn't matter.

Comment: I make this: https://codepen.io/online123/pen/xxwyXXr But it makes the space between colums variable. How to make is static. Variable should be the left and right side (space).

Comment: how mean you want it in a sequence of  **1,2,3,4,5** from left to right not like now how it is **1,6,11** ? waiting for your reply

Comment: Sequence doesn't matter. It could be other sequence like on image. Check here: https://codepen.io/online123/pen/xxwyXXr

Comment: @inside_tank please have look the answer above i have edited it please run the code. If it is what you want let me know.

Comment: @inside_tank open it in **full page** to see the effect.

Comment: This is not what I want. See screen: https://i.imgur.com/BIh6PEL.png

Comment: You can remove these space like i just update answer please see it is static.

Comment: Now there are 6 columns on start. And the @ media don't works. @ media works only <1350 -> 2 columns.

Comment: And "Flex item 1 and 2" are missing.